# CodeIgniter - Store array data to database table

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to save multiple selection or checkbox to database table in 1 column and then parse to get it in array ?

I have this screnario:

I have a right permission, and id 1,2,3 and 5 has access to a page.

```
id,username,password,right
1, admin, 123, 1
2, john, john, 2
3, doe, doe, array(1,2,3)
```

model:

```
$insert_member = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'right' => $this->input->post('right')          
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('members', $insert_member);
            return $insert;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): Try below:

```
$right_value   = $this->input->post('right');
$insert_member = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'right' => json_encode($right_value)
        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('members', $insert_member);
        return $insert;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice move, so after that, to get on view ? i need to parse it again to json_decode ? as i will need to check if is in array. Thanks

Comment: @Dario, yes `json_decode` will turn it back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

For permissions you can use [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). These allow you to store multiple values in one column by using binary. In a standard int(11) column you can have a number up to 32 bits in binary, or 4,294,967,295 in decimal (unsigned).

What you do is you assign each permission a bit in the column, so for example if you have 3 pages and you want to control access to each page you have the following:

```
        |  Page 3  |  Page 2  |  Page 1  |  Right (Binary / Decimal)
User 1  |     0    |     0    |     0    |     000 / 0
User 2  |     0    |     0    |     1    |     001 / 1
User 3  |     0    |     1    |     0    |     010 / 2
User 4  |     0    |     1    |     1    |     011 / 3
User 5  |     1    |     0    |     0    |     100 / 4
User 6  |     1    |     0    |     1    |     101 / 5
```

etc..  You can have any combination, and the binary bits don't interfere with each other.

Then once you load the information back out of the database you can use the [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to check whether a user has the correct permissions. So to check if a user has permission to access page 2 you would do the following:

```
// We use 2 here because page 2 is the second bit, which is 2 in decimal
if(($right & 2) == 2) {
    // has access...
} else {
    // doesn't have access...
}
```